# How does inotify work when multiple processes are watching the same files?

Tags: linux, files, kernel, inotify

I have read some stuff about inodes and open file limits - what happens when multiple processes are watching the same files using inotify? is there ever a problem, or does the kernel/system handle that without any issues?

I guess for example if I ran these two at the same time:

```
(inotifywait -m /path -e create -e moved_to) &
(inotifywait -m /path -e create -e moved_to) &
```

Comment: You question seem to just fade out. You guess that if you run those two at the same time, then what?

Comment: how does it work, and under what circumstances might there be problems

Comment: It's a SMOP. System keeps a list of interested processes, and notifies each one.

Comment: thanks link to SMOP?

Comment: And what is your guess? (edit question to make it clear)